# List event Item Updating is not firing

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers

I have added a list item updating event to a document library but I cant see it running please tell me how to check if it is running, I also have put a log entry in the event receivers code but cant see it in the ULS logs.

Please note that it is running locally but not on the production.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if there's a registration of your receiver on your list. One way is to get the great [SharePoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/51438/download/146573) tool and see the event receivers registered for you list as at [this](http://gyazo.com/15c4b2c58844d0e61c62da1a1fc2884d.png) screen:
[image]

Comment: I see let me check

Comment: I am trying to use Sharepoint Manager 2007 but on opening the site node I am getting Access Denied msg

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the element.xml file that's attached with the event receiver contain the event in it 
like :

```
 <Receiver>
      <Name>MyDocsEventReceiverItemUpdating</Name>
      <Type>ItemUpdating</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>SourceSite.MyDocsEventReceiver.MyDocsEventReceiver</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
```

As when you override new function in event receiver class VS mayn't add the equivalent xml for it in element.xml file